# Cannot convert from utf16 little endian to utf8

Tags: c++, visual-studio, utf-8, stl, utf-16

Desperately need your help.
"C:\Temp\1 (2).txt" is a testing file in little endian UTF16:

```
3C 00 64 00 69 00 76 00 3E 00
<div>
```

Trying to get UTF8 from this file by the following code:[image]

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>
#include <vector>
using std::string;
using std::wstring;
using std::vector;


std::ifstream logfile("C:\\Temp\\1 (2).txt", std::ios::binary);
vector<char> paste_code_buf((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(logfile)), (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
wstring paste_code;
paste_code.assign(paste_code_buf.begin(), paste_code_buf.end());

std::wstring_convert < std::codecvt_utf8_utf16 < wchar_t, 0x10ffffUL, std::little_endian>> cv;
string mbs = cv.to_bytes(paste_code);
```

Looking at mbs at debugger ( Visual Studio 2013) shows no conversion has happened.
What's wrong?

Comment: You fill `paste_code_buf` with bytes from the file; every other byte is 0. Then you expand every byte to `wchar_t` and assign to `paste_code`. There, every other `wchar_t` is zero. Then you convert those `wchar_t`s back to bytes; zero `wchar_t`s become zero bytes. You need to make it so every **two** bytes turn into a single `wchar_t`.

Comment: @Igor: this should be an answer. Thanks a lot!